# How can I let .NET wrapper for Rebar decide the mouse cursor?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, pinvoke

I'm making a `Rebar` wrapper for .NET. Here's how I've made my control.

```
public class Rebar : Control {

    public Rebar() : base() {
        //Control won't even work if I let UserPaint enabled
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, false);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ClassName = "ReBarWindow32"; //REBARCLASSNAME
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000080; //WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
            //Windows Forms will control the position and size, not the native control
            cp.Style |= 0x00000004 | 0x00000008; //CCS_NORESIZE and CCS_NOPARENTALIGN
            return cp;
        }
    }

}
```

I tested my control by adding a `REBARBANDINFO` into the control and IT WORKED.

```
REBARBANDINFO info = new REBARBANDINFO();
info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(REBARBANDINFO));
info.fMask = RBBIM_TEXT; // 0x00000004
info.lpText = "example";
SendMessage(this.Handle, RB_INSERTBANDW, -1, ref myband);
```

I won't include the implementation of my p/invoke signatures because everything is fine there.

## The problem starts here

The control doesn't work the way I've expected, the Rebar cursor isn't respected and `Cursor` property takes control over the cursor, it even overrides the resize cursor.

### Expectation

[image: Expectation of Rebar wrapper]

### Reality

[image: Reality of Rebar wrapper]

### Is that even possible? Yes, it is

Check out this example of a `ListView`. It IS possible to make a Control that respects its original cursor messages.

[image: ListView example]

How can I make my `Rebar` decide the mouse cursor instead of `Cursor` property?

**Aditional:** I've done my best to ask a good question. I double-checked the question to ensure it can be understood.

Comment: Normally this sort of thing is done by tracking MouseMove and comparing the coordinates to a known visual element in order to change the cursor dynamically; at least that's what I do in my custom controls ;).   Is there anything useful in `RBN_SPLITTERDRAG` or `RBN_BEGINDRAG`? (I've not used Rebar before)  I'm surprised there is no `RBN_DRAG`

Comment: `RBN_SPLITTERDRAG` and similar notifications (they're not messages) are not useful for this because cursor can only be set while dragging. Don't forget the `Cursor` property affects the whole control.

Comment: _"...they're not messages..."_ - what do you mean?  They are notifications _"[...sent in the form of a WM_NOTIFY message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774427(v=vs.85).aspx)"_.

Comment: _"Cursor property affects the whole control"_ - yes, but there is nothing stopping you from changing it during a mouse move.  That's what I do all the time.  Like I said, during a mouse move you perform a hittest and set the cursor to something appropriate depending on what the mouse is over

Comment: AFAIK `ListView` does more than hit-testing, the cursor even changes when cursor is over the separator

Comment: ListView is different, the header is implemented by another control which handles its own messages.  Or in other words, the ListView wrapper itself never sees anything that happens in the header beyond the messages that the header control intentionally sends to its parent.  Makes customizing the headers pretty tricky btw.  Rebar probably doesn't work that way (look with Spy++) so you have to explicitly pass relevant messages to the native Rebar with DefWndProc() to stop the Control class message handling from being helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Control` class handles `WM_SETCURSOR` and has its own logic.

As an option you can override `WndProc` and let the `DefWndProc` handle `WM_SETCURSOR`:

```
const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR)
        base.DefWndProc(ref m);
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you deserve my upvote and my 'answer mark'